# Starting activity from preference menu item not working

Tags: java, android

Trying to make a Beginner level Sudoku Game

Using Android Studio 2.3.3, API 25

Game's Main Activity java file(GameActivity.java)

```
package oscorp.sudoku;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View newGameButton = findViewById(R.id.newGameButton);
    newGameButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.aboutButton:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.newGameButton:
                openNewGameDialog();
                break;

        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onCreateItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";

public void openNewGameDialog(){

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.new_game_title)
            .setItems(R.array.difficulty, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
                    startGame(i);
                }
            });

}

private void startGame(int i){
    Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on" + i);
}

}
```

Game's Layout (activity_game.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="40dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/continueButton_text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_gameButton_text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/aboutButton_text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exitButton_text"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Game's Pref's file (Prefs.java)

```
package oscorp.sudoku;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}

}
```

settings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="music"
    android:title="@string/music_title"
    android:summary="@string/music_summary"
    android:defaultValue="true" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="hints"
    android:title="@string/hints_title"
    android:summary="@string/hints_summary"
    android:defaultValue="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

array.xml file that is to be displayed when the menu item settings is selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="difficulty">
    <item>@string/easy_label</item>
    <item>@string/medium_label</item>
    <item>@string/hard_label</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

I've uploaded all the necessary files.
while testing the app when I go to the overflow menu that is having the settings option and on selecting that option nothing is happening, the settings.xml file should be inflated and launched.

Also on clicking the NEW GAME button nothing is happening but the array.xml file should be inflated and launched.

Android Studio is showing no errors or warnings but one unused method alert for the onOptionsItemSelected() method in GameActivity.java file.

Don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: It's showing that method does not override method from it's superclass

Comment: 1. Your GameActivity code does not contain `onOptionsItemSelected()` (so selecting a menu item will have no consequences), but it contains a method `onCreateItemSelected()` with the code which should go into the missing method. I think this is some copy-paste-error. Simply name the method correctly.

Comment: 2. The AlertDialog has to be not only configured but also created and shown!